# What is the proper way to list all youtube broadcasts on behalf of the Content Owner (Youtube Partner) using Youtube API V3?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I tried this:

Went here - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Set the following parameters:

part - snippet

eventType - live (Also tried, completed)

forContentOwner - true

onBehalfOfContentOwner - 'Partner ID'

type - video

I have properly authenticated using the partners login credentials by switching on the OAuth at the top right of the form.

The documentation says, if 'eventType' is set, then the 'type' should be set to 'video' and if 'forContentOwner' is set then onBehlafOfContentOwner should be supplied and should be properly authenticated all of which I clearly did but I get the following error:

```
400 Bad Request

- Show headers -

{
  "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.search",
    "reason": "invalidSearchFilter",
    "message": "Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": ""
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions."
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the debug info: video_filter is unsupported in combination with for_content_owner filter.

So you can not do it this way.

Comment: Hi Ibrahim, I've seen almost all of your videos and learnt a lot from them. I just want to know if there is any way to list all live broadcasts of a particular youtube partner who owns a lot of channels.  I'm trying to make a javascript/php script that inserts a cuePoint at regular intervals(like every 15 mins) into the live broadcasts.

Comment: I requested this feature internally. Right now it doesn't exist. You can file a feature request in issue tracker and let me know it's id to track the progress. https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Enhancement%20Request)

Comment: I just posted a feature request - https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5763